# Wordpress Custom Post type Permalink not working

Tags: wordpress, post, types, permalinks

I created custom post type on my wordpress site,

when ever i create a new post inside a CPT, the permalink doesnot set as the title, how ever, it sets as "first post name - (number-ascending)"

how do i fix the issue?

Comment: Did you try updating permalinks?

Answer (score 1):

In the Settings → Permalinks screen, Change Permalink structure to have post name.

[image]

Read more about permalinks here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks